# RavenDB count index including zero values

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb, nosql

I have a list of items `{Id, Name, CategoryId}` and a list of categories `{Id, Name, IsActive}`.

How to get a list `{CategoryId, Count}` **including categories that have zero items**.

Currently I have such index:

```
public class CategoryCountIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Item, CategoryCountIndex.Result>
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public CategoryCountIndex()
    {
        Map = items => from item in items

            select new Result
            {
                CategoryId = item.CategoryId,
                Count = 1
            };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
            group result by result.CategoryId
            into c
            select new Result
            {
                CategoryId = c.Key,
                Count = c.Sum(x => x.Count)
            };
    }
}
```

What is the best way to improve/change my solution in order to have categories with no items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed my earlier answer as it proved to be incorrect. In this case you can actually use a MultiMap/Reduce index to solve your problem.

Try using the following index:

```
public class Category_Items : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Category_Items.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public Category_Items()
    {
        AddMap<Item>(items =>
            from item in items
            select new 
            {
                CategoryId = item.CategoryId,
                Count = 1
            });

        AddMap<Category>(categories =>
            from category in categories
            select new 
            {
                CategoryId = category.Id,
                Count = 0
            });


        Reduce = results =>
            from result in results
            group result by result.CategoryId into g
            select new ReduceResult
            {
                CategoryId = g.Key,
                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
            };
    }
}
```

This will result in the following (three categories, but one without items): 
[image: Query result from index]

Now you can use a Result Transformer if you want to display the Category Name.

Hope this helps!